# the array is only written to, never read from

Tags: java, encryption

I try to test this code for encrypting and decrypting. By using `dst = new String(baos.toByteArray()); return dst;` 
I can't decrypt the cipher text. However when I use `byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(src);`
I didn't manage to run the program. How can I fix this?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;    
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;    
import javax.crypto.Cipher;    
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;    
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;    
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;    
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;    
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class FileEncryption {

    //Initial Vector
    public static final byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };      

    //EncryptAndDecrypt String -> Input : PlainText + Return : CipherText+DecipherText
    public static String encryptString(String src) throws Exception
    {
        String dst="";
        //Not Input!
        if(src == null || src.length()==0)
            return "";

        //Encryption Setting
        byte[] k="Multimediaproces".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec Key = new SecretKeySpec(k,"AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,Key,ivspec);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        CipherOutputStream cout = new CipherOutputStream(baos,encryptCipher);
        cout.write(src.getBytes());
        cout.flush();               //ByteOutputStream -> Write Encryption Text
        cout.close();           
        dst = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(baos.toByteArray());
        return dst;
    }   

    //String src -> EncryptedData
    public static String decryptString(String src) throws Exception 
    {
        //src value is Encrypted Value!
        //So, src value -> Not Byte!
        String dst="";
        byte[] encryptedBytes = src.getBytes();         
        //Not Input!
        if(src == null || src.length()==0)
            return "";          
        //Decryption Setting
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        byte[] k="Multimediaproces".getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec Key = new SecretKeySpec(k,"AES");
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,Key,ivspec); 

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedBytes);
        CipherInputStream cin = new CipherInputStream(bais,decryptCipher);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while((read=cin.read(buf))>=0)  //reading encrypted data!
        {
            baos.write(buf,0,read);     //writing decrypted data!
        }

        // closing streams
        cin.close();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(src);
        return dst;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three errors in your sample code:

1. It doesn't compile because of  `byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(src);` at the end of `decryptString` method
2. Because you have printed out the encrypted string as a hexidecimal representation, you must convert it back to a normal byte array before trying to decrypt it. In `decryptString` you should call `byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(src);` instead. This will convert back to the `byte[]`  instead of the hexidecimal representation.
3. You need a line which converts `baos` to a `String` at the end of `decrpytString`. This is as simple as `dst = baos.toString();`

   With these three changes, I was able to encrypt and decrypt a String.

Comment: thanks buddy. but after I used dst = baos.toString(); still got the same problem. if using byte[] encryptedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(src); also have the same issue

Comment: @noobie, could you post your new code and the specific error you are getting?